# Question on PositioningManager Data Source

Tags: here-api

I'm working on integrate the Navigation into an Android app and had a customer report that it took 30 seconds for the app to detect that they want off route before re-routing them.  This led me to look at the different data sources.  I see the following options.

Does anyone have any details on which is going to be the most accurate and efficient ?  I am using the GPS_NETWORK and the devices have cellular connections.

````
Abstract class that defines the interface for providing positions updates from an automotive location data source (e.g.

LocationDataSourceDevice    
Abstract class that defines the interface for providing positions updates from a platform location data source.

LocationDataSourceGoogleServices    
Abstract class that defines the interface for providing positions updates from the google location services data source.

LocationDataSourceHERE  
Abstract class that defines the interface for providing positions updates from a HERE hybrid location data source.```
````

Answer (score 0):

For now, we are not providing the option for advance positioning in GSM, CDMA, Wifi networks etc. You can refer our documentation guide to look into the features.